# Cannot get this simple code to work from the Michael Hartl Tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html, railstutorial.org

So I am very new to rails and I am taking this tutorial and ran into the following problem.

So I have set up my view/helpers/application_helper.rb like this:

```
module ApplicationHelper
# Returns the full title on a per-page basis.
 def full_title(page_title)
  base_title = "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
  if page_title.empty?
   base_title
  else
  "#{base_title} | #{page_title}"
  end
 end 
end
```

and my view/layouts/application.html.erb like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %> <%= javascript_include_tag     "application" %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
<%= yield %>
</body>
</html>
```

and the view/layouts/about.html.erb like this:

```
<% provide(:title, 'About Us') %>
<h1>About Us</h1>
<p>
The <a href="http://railstutorial.org/">Ruby on Rails Tutorial</a> is a project to make      a book and screencasts to teach web development with <a href="http://rubyonrails.org/">Ruby     on Rails</a>. This
is the sample application for the tutorial.
</p>
```

Now, from my under standing that means it should display the 'About Us' page title like this

"Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | About Us"

Correct?

however all I see is:

"About Us"

I have tried removing the

```
<% provide(:title, 'About Us') %>
```

and placing it all over the place.

Any suggestions?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full_title method in the application helper only changes the *title* of your html page (see line 4 of the application layout). The h1 "About Us" will remain static.

Note that if you're using the Chrome browser, you won't be able to see the title at the top of your browser (see section [3.3.1](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages#sec-testing_a_title_change) of the Hartl's Rails tutorial).

Comment: AHH! I glazed over the part about using chrome. Thanks!